# Image data generator for my (x, 12, 370, 235, 3) dataset

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, image-preprocessing, d3dimage

I have made a model with 12 2D CNN inputs. I suddenly realized that the ImageDataGenerator from

`from keras.preprocessing import image`

don't accept inputs with more than 4 dimensions or as the error message stated it:

> ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (4, 12, 370, 235, 3))

### My model:

[image]